# Redirecting css/js files to dir path with .htaccess in Express static

Tags: css, node.js, .htaccess, express, ejs

I made a nodejs-express project which have some static html content and styles. 
I used express-static like this to get assets file :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views/assets'));
```

This works fine when I start a node server like this: `node server.js`
But I have a GoDaddy shared hosting with apache2 pre-configured and I have to get rid of the port on which this node server started and I can't use port 80 as there are other static pages already hosted on that server.

So, I added a .htaccess file in root of the project dir :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:8080/  [P,L]
```

This is redirecting the page to http://www.example.com/myproject/ but the static files like css and js added in `ejs` files are getting 404. They got the path like www.example.com/css/main.css, wherein local scenario the css files would be found in http://localhost:8080/css/main.css

Can I add a proxy in .htaccess to achieve this

How can I fix the problem without removing express-static or changing css and js paths to relative?